# Can't connect to my own minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

for more context it's a 1.12.2 modded forge server running on my own pc, other people are able to join but when I try to connect it returns the error "io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception connection refused no further information." I'm also unable to port forward due to me not being able to access router settings so I'm port forwarding it with Utorrent.
As for things I've tried:
-restarting my pc
-restarting my internet (I haven't tried resetting the router yet)
-redownloading minecraft
-recreating the server
-updating java

As a post note, the server is running perfectly fine and the problem my connection to the server

Comment: Do any of these https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/316791, https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334342 have answers that could work for you?

Comment: Is this only on your server or does this happen on all servers?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your own server by adding the address "Localhost" in your minecraft server browser?

Comment: it's only happening on my server and localhost is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information" error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316791/how-to-solve-the-io-netty-channel-abstractchannelannotatedconnectexception-co). Failing that the question is off-topic as tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score -1):

You have either two mods that don't work together well and were too much for your computer to handle, or too many mods that your game crashed trying to load in all those textures, or your connection is bad. Either of the first two happens very frequently on a nearly full hard drive, like that one glitch that took chunks and moved them to other parts of your world that just so happen to have the same requirements as having two incompatible mods/too many mods to load in.